# How to include/import custom js files into vue project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I have downloaded html template from some site and now want to convert that whole template into vue cli project.The template has jquery and other custom js files.For jquery and bootstrap I used npm package but for other custom js I don't know how can I make it run.below is index.html file inside public folder in vue cli project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>License Renewal</title>
  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link href="css/nepali.datepicker.v3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="css/revolution-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Favicon-->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ezee-logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/ezee-logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Responsive -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/respond.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

    </div>
    <!--Scroll to top-->
    <div class="scroll-to-top scroll-to-target" data-target=".main-header"><span class="icon fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span></div>


    <script src="js/nepali.datepicker.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appear.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <!--Google Map APi Key-->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
    <script src="js/map-script.js"></script>

    <!--End Google Map APi-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $.getScript('js/nepali.datepicker.v3.min.js')
                .done(function(script, textStatus) {
                  console.log(textStatus)
                  /*var mainInput = document.getElementById("nepali-datepicker");
                  mainInput.nepaliDatePicker();
                  console.log('date');
                  console.log(mainInput);*/
                });


      })
    </script>

    <script>
      $('.motor-block').on('click',function () {
        test('application');
        console.log('yes');
      })
      function test(elID)
      {
        var dest = document.getElementById(elID);
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
          scrollTop: $(dest).offset().top -25
        }, 500);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

below script files are those I am talking about.How can I run them?

```
 <script src="js/nepali.datepicker.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appear.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

below is main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Main from './Main'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import jQuery from 'jquery'
global.jQuery=jQuery
global.$=jQuery
let Bootstrap=require('bootstrap')
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(Main)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: the same way you did with jquery (but not all in main)

Comment: Ya i can use npm package for jquery but for template specific js how can i run it

Comment: all them libs are on npm, for *template* specific js it would be put in the vue instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few routes you can take here. The easiest by far would be to find the files on NPM and install them in your project, use Webpack or Gulp, to copy the files over to the public JS path that is used in Index.js. Another way is to find those files online and copy them by hand (copy whole file contents, paste to new local file) and save to the template core files public path you wish.

Comment: Yes @Rylan i can use npm packages but what about template specific js like script.js I cannot find package for it.I should run them after DOM is setup i mean at the end.